# Prestashop Friendly URL's

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, seo, prestashop, clean-urls

I've been trying to create a second option of url rewrites to a product inside [prestashop](https://www.prestashop.com). In the standard Prestashop installation at the SEO & URL's section i've got the following products url build-up:

```
{category:/}{id}-{rewrite}-{ean13}.html
```

This creates the following products url:

```
https://www.example.com/{category-name}/{product-id}/{product-name}/{ean13}.html
```

What i would like to add is an option for various reasons to acces a products page through the following url build up:

```
ean/{ean13}.html
```

The result url would be something like the following example:

```
https://www.example.com/ean13/{ean13}.html
```

**NOTE, ID is a standard required field of the url build up, this means that i can't use: "Just ajust the url build up" as an answer.**

Is there a module, addon, or piece of code out there that would be able to generate these kind of structures?

I did find some "Remove ID's from pretty url's" modules but that doesn't give me the result i'm searching for. Only partially since it only removes the ID's.

It wouldn't be a problem if it's a redirect to the standard url build up as mentioned in the first {code} segment. I know i could write rewrite rules in my .htacces file but to do this for every product would be a lot of work so i was wondering if there is a more easy way of achieving this.

As always thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

If you're fine with redirect to standard URL then the solution is quite easy with a module.

1. Create a module that uses hook `moduleRoutes` and configure a friendly URL to use module controller
2. Create a module front controller
3. Run a db query in your custom controller to check if a product with requested EAN exists
4. Redirect to product page if product exists, otherwise to 404 page or something

I assume you know how to write modules and controllers, so I won't write entire code just the relevant bits.

Hook `moduleRoutes` in module class.

In this hook you can configure a friendly URL for your custom controller.

```php
public function hookModuleRoutes()
{
    return [
        'mymodulename-mycontrollername-root' => [
            'rule' => 'ean13/{:ean13}.html',
            'controller' => 'mycontrollername',
            'keywords' => [
                'ean13' => ['regexp' => '[0-9]+', 'param' => 'ean13']
            ],
            'params' => [
                'fc' => 'module',
                'module' => 'mymodulename'
            ]
        ]
    ];
}
```

So visiting `https://www.example.com/ean13/12345.html` will run your module controller and a GET variable `ean13` will have a value of `12345`.

Then create `mycontrollername` module controller where you can use `postProcess()` method to check if EAN exists.

```php
public function postProcess()
{
    $query = new DbQuery();
    $query->select('id_product')
          ->from('product_attribute', 'pa')
          ->where('pa.ean13 = ' . (int)Tools::getValue('ean13'))
    $productId = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->getValue($query);
    if ($productId) {
        Tools::redirect($this->context->link->getProductLink($productId));
    }

    Tools::redirect('pagenotfound');
}
```

In query we check in `product_attribute` table as product combinations can have their own EAN13 and you also want those EAN13's to redirect to product page.

The basics of this answer is most commonly used to replace core product search controller with a custom and SEO friendly one.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: Hi, could you maybe help me out? With this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49430883/creating-a-url-rewrite-module-in-prestashop I got some issues while accessing the url. I thought it would work correctly but sadly i didn't find the solution yet

Comment: Could you maybe provide me with a full code example?