# Creating a url rewrite module in prestashop

Tags: php, function, redirect, module, prestashop

I'm trying to build my own custom [prestashop](https://www.prestashop.com) module. The module is very simple. It needs to read the url and if the url of the visitor is equal to an product code it needs to redirect the user to that specific product page. For this i'm using the following url:

```
www.example.com/ean13/{ean13}
```

So when the visitor, for example, tries to visit the page:

```
www.example.com/ean13/1121312341
```

a query has to start running and has to search for that 'ean13' product code. If the product code exists the user needs to be redirected to the specific products page.

So i've already build the basics of my module and currently the setup is the image below:

[image: Module setup]

As you can see the module only consists of two files. The main module configuration file "customRoute.php" and a controller in "controllers/front/routeController.php"

The code of both files below:

**customRoute.php**

```
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
{
    exit;
}

class customRoute extends Module {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'customRoute';
        $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
        $this->version = '1.0.0';
        $this->author = 'Niels van Enckevort';
        $this->need_instance = 0;
        $this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.6', 'max' => _PS_VERSION_);
        $this->bootstrap = true;

        parent::__construct();

        $this->displayName = $this->l('custom routes');
        $this->description = $this->l('Custom routes.');

        $this->confirmUninstall = $this->l('Are you sure you want to uninstall?');

        if (!Configuration::get('customRoute'))
            $this->warning = $this->l('No name provided');
    }

    public function install()
    {
        if (Shop::isFeatureActive())
            Shop::setContext(Shop::CONTEXT_ALL);

        if (!parent::install() ||
            !$this->registerHook('ModuleRoutes') ||
            !$this->registerHook('header') ||
            !Configuration::updateValue('customRoute', 'my test')
        )
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    public function uninstall()
    {
        if (!parent::uninstall() ||
            !Configuration::deleteByName('customRoute')
        )
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    public function hookDisplayHeader()
    {
        $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'css/mymodule.css', 'all');
    }

    public function hookModuleRoutes($params)
    {
        return [
                'customRoute-customRouteRouteControllerModuleFrontController-root' => [
                'rule' => 'ean13/{:ean13}/{rewrite}.html',
                'controller' => 'routeController',
                'keywords' => [
                    'ean13' => ['regexp' => '[0-9]+', 'param' => 'ean13']
                ],
                'params' => [
                    'fc' => 'module',
                    'module' => 'customRoute'
                ]
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

**routeController.php**

```
class CustomRouteRouteControllerModuleFrontController extends moduleFrontController {
    public function postProcess()
    {
        $query = new DbQuery();
        $query->select('id_product')
            ->from('product_attribute', 'pa')
            ->where('pa.ean13 = ' . (int)Tools::getValue('ean13'));
        $productId = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->getValue($query);
        if ($productId) {
            Tools::redirect($this->context->link->getProductLink($productId));
        } else {
            Tools::redirect('pagenotfound');
        }
    }
}
```

I need to mention that i did obtain this code with some help since this is the first custom module i'm writing. I think i'm missing a, or multiple key items and hope that someone could help me out with those things.

The module is installed and loaded in the front so it has nothing to do with the install but with the functions build up i'm using.

if you have any questions please ask them in the comments section
As always, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well your module class is ok, but your controller is not.

I've answered this already before I think but module front controller class must be declared as following:

`class MyModuleNameControllerNameModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController`

so your controller should be

`class CustomRouteRouteControllerModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController`

**Edit**

Issue is having `Controller` in controller name and controller filename.

Renaming `routeController.php` to `route.php`, `CustomRouteRouteControllerModuleFrontController` to `CustomRouteRouteModuleFrontController` and changing `hookModuleRoutes` to

```
return [
    'customroute-route-root' => [
        'rule' => 'ean13/{:ean13}.html',
        'controller' => 'route',
        'keywords' => [
            'ean13' => ['regexp' => '[0-9]+', 'param' => 'ean13']
        ],
        'params' => [
            'fc' => 'module',
            'module' => 'customroute'
        ]
    ]
];
```

solves it and routing works properly.

Comment: Yes you did, and logically it is the right solution but it still isn't doing the trick. Could you maybe explain the full steps of how to achieve the above? I've also updated my code with your name segment mentions. I found out about that part about an hour ago.

Comment: As you've mentioned in my previous question i had to do the following steps: 1. Create a module that uses hook moduleRoutes and configure a friendly URL to use module controller
2. Create a module front controller
Run a db query in your custom controller to check if a product with requested EAN exists
Redirect to product page if product exists, otherwise to 404 page or something ,,,,, So step one: I've created the module with the code above. And added a friendly url in the SEO section to my module. Step 2, the frontcontroller of my module is also in the code above. Aswell as step 3 and 4.

Comment: Yes but your `hookModuleRoutes` is not the same as my answer in previous question.

Comment: Also when you use hook `moduleRoutes` there in no need to configure anything in SEO section of backend.

Comment: I see that the first line of my return differs from the previous answer. So would changing it to your previous template:         'mymodulename-mycontrollername-root' => [
Solve the issue? since i would then place:             'customRoute-customRouteRouteControllerModuleFrontController-root' => [ I've placed an update in my code above

Comment: In `hookModuleRoutes` you need this `'customRoute-routeController-root' => `. It's only the controller class declaration that needs the long naming.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167359/discussion-between-deathstorm-and-thedrot).

Comment: Deathstorm
So i've done the following steps: Rename the controller file to just routeController.php (left the long controller decleration within the file the same). And i've added the "customRoute-routeController-root" to the hook decleration in my main module class. Still no result if i go to myshop.com/ean13/{ean13} i'm still getting an error
I've tested to see if the module is readable from the backend by checking the SEO section and "add new page", to see if my module would be listed and it is

Comment: Hi sir @TheDrot, could you please help in :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62458761/friendly-url-problem-in-front-module-prestashop ? Your usual posts are very helpful

Comment: how do you access to the parameter {:/ean13} in a front controller?

Comment: @abrfra `Tools::getValue('ean13')` should work. For PS1.6 at least, I have not touched prestashop in 2 years so I don't know for the latest versions.